# Email Notification to subscribers while publishing an api in WS02 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there a possibility to notify the subscribed users via email that a new api has been published & is available in the api store

Answer (score 0):

There is **NO** such option.

However in case of a new version of the API, we can do something to alert the user who are already subscribed to the old version.

For more info visit [Managing an API Lifecycle](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM140/Managing+an+API+Lifecycle)

And for the list of features that APIM provides, [APIM Features](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM100/API+Manager+Features)